# snowflake performance with emr spark

Tags: performance, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-emr

I need to process the data stored in s3 and store it in snowflake.
During several tests, I discovered a performance issue.

common config

- Data **A** (stored in s3): 20GB
- Data **B** (stored in s3 and snowflake): 8.5KB
- Operation: left outer join
- Using EMR(spark) r5.4xlarge(5)

when i read Data A and Data B(snowflake), it elapsed more than 1 hour, 12 mins

```scala
val Adf= spark.read.parquet("s3://path") 

var sfOptions = Map.apply(
"sfURL" -> "XXXXX.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com",
"sfUser" -> XXXXX",
"sfPassword" -> "XXXX",
"sfDatabase" -> "XXX",
"sfSchema" -> "XXXX",
"sfWarehouse" -> "XXXX"
)

val Bdf: DataFrame = spark.sqlContext.read
.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
.options(sfOptions)
.option("dbtable","XXXX")
.load()

val resultDF = Adf.join(Bdf, Seq("CNTY"), "leftouter")

resultDF.write
.fomat(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
.options(sfOptions)
.option("dbtable","t_result_from spark")
.opton("parallelism","8")
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.save()
```

but when i read Data A and Data B(s3), it elapsed just 10 mins.

```scala
val Adf= spark.read.parquet("s3://path") 

val Bdf  spark.read.option("header","true").csv("s3://path") 

val resultDF = Adf.join(Bdf, Seq("CNTY"), "leftouter")

resultDF.write
.fomat(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
.options(sfOptions)
.option("dbtable","t_result_from spark_2")
.opton("parallelism","8")
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.save()
```

why is there a different performance between reading on S3 and reading on snowflake?

Comment: What size of warehouse are you running in Snowflake?

Comment: i used 3x-large.

Comment: If you create an External Table in Snowflake for DataA and then run the whole process in Snowflake, how does the performance compare to the Spark-only process?

Comment: I tried and it took 53.7secs

Comment: I tried another test, when I read Data B from snowflake and write it in s3 and re-read it again, it took 5 minutes.

Comment: I think that all shows the benefit of doing as much as possible on a single platform. Get the data into S3 or Snowflake as efficiently as possible and then query the data there.